# ADFS setup creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, adfs

I got a request to create a new setup of ADFS. The request is like to test SAML authentication for application using ADFS as the IdP.

I don't have clue on it. I refer some stuff on internet.., but could not find which one to go with.

I have to launch machines on AWS and need to create in them,. can someone please assist this..

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Windows Server VM in AWS (not an AWS expert) and then:

- Install the AD FS [Role Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/install-the-ad-fs-role-service)
- Configure a [Federation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/configure-a-federation-server)
- Configure an AD FS [relying party trust](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-an-ad-fs-relying-party-trust) (this example is with B2C but the overall method is the same)